# Async pipe is not working with same observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

I am using async pipe in view, to load data dynamically in the view. However, It is not loading any data.

I need to change values of observables, few times in a page, like reload page, load more values, and change news content based on the categories of the news.

I used ChangeDetectorRef, detectChanges(), but without any luck.

```
ngOnInit() {
   if (this.isFirstRun) {
     this.items$ = this.apiService.getNewsByCategory(
                  this.categoryId = (this.categoryId === 0 ? 1 : this.categoryId));
     this.cg.detectChanges();
   }
 }

//NgOnChanges

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
if (this.isFirstRun) {
  const chg = changes.categoryId;
  this.items$ = this.apiService.getNewsByCategory(chg.currentValue);
  this.cg.detectChanges();
}
```

}

```
// In the views i used these things

<div *ngIf="(items$| async) as news ; else loading">
// View stuff here

</div>
```

items$ must reload while any change is detected, i.e. CategoryId is chages. It is not working in this case.

However, ngOnInit is working fine.

Any help is much appreciated, No ideas is generating in my head.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better pattern towards your problem, i.e use a separate `subject` as a trigger and you don't need to manually detect changes for async pipe to work

```
  refreshItems$ = new Subject()

  items$ = this.refreshItems$.asObservable().pipe(
    switchMap(param => this.apiService.getNewsByCategory(param)))
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.isFirstRun) {
      this.refreshItems$.next()
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.isFirstRun) {
      this.refreshItems$.next(changes.categoryId)
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry there were a lot of typo in my code. i corrected them and see if it works.

Comment: Can u setup a simple stackbliz I can help u debug

Comment: sure, I will setup.

Answer (score 0):

If the default change detector didn't detect your change, then it will not invoke ngOnChanges. So if that is your case, then you can manually check for changes using ngDoCheck.

Comment: ngOnChanges is working. I can see it is executing that statement, but can't see changes in View.